# What is the name for words such as "thus", "hence", "however", etc.?

Tags: vocabulary, synonyms, terminology

I need to write my Master's thesis in English but I often find myself repeating words such as "hence", "thus" and "however". I suspect resouces like word banks exist to help novice writers like me but I don't now how to call this kind of words and hence I cannot look them up on the Internet. Does anyone know the term I am looking for and, maybe, know of any such resource i could use?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

They belong to the category of **adverbs**. But they function as **adjuncts**, or more technically, *connective adjuncts*.

The main function of connective adjuncts is to *connect* two utterances while expressing the semantic relationship between them. There are four main types of connection that be expressed: additive, contrast, causal, and temporal.

Note also, *adjuncts* are not necessarily realized by adverbs; they can also be realized by:

prepositional phrases:*by the way*, *on the top of that* 
adjective phrases: *last of all*, *better still* 
finite clauses: *that is to say*, *what is more* 
and non-finite clauses: *to sum up*, *to cap it all*.